# My Python code is not outputting anything?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to teach myself Python with the *Python Crash Course* book by Eric Matthes and I seem to be having difficulties with excercise 5-9 regarding using if tests to test empty lists.

**Here is the question:**

5-9. No Users: Add an if test to hello_admin.py to make sure the list of users is not empty.

• If the list is empty, print the message We need to find some users!

• Remove all of the usernames from your list, and make sure the correct message is printed.

**Here is my code from hello_admin.py:**

```
usernames = ['admin', 'user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_4']

for username in usernames:

    if username is 'admin':
        print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
    else:
        print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")
```

**Now here is my code for 5-9 which is not outputting anything:**

```
usernames = []

for username in usernames:

    if username is 'admin':
        print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
    else:
        print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")
    if usernames:
        print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")
    else:
        print("We need to find some users!")
```

Does anyone having any feedback for why my code is not outputting: "We need to find some users!" Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, you can format your code by indenting four spacess. See the [help topic on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Otherwise, well done on a solid first question.

Comment: @FrankTan, I often find it a hassle to manually add indents for each line when formatting code here. Is there an easy way to add four spaces quickly without copy-and-pasting four whitespaces?

Comment: Unless your code is not already indented before pasting it here, won't stackoverflow automatically indent it according to your code style when you place the code between the curly braces thing?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim Yes, there is. Begin your code block by indenting four spaces. Type your first line. For each successive line, use `Ctrl + Enter` instead of just `Enter`. This will automatically indent for you. There's also more on this [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: `if var is 'string'` is a bad habit to have. It only works for very short strings. You should be comparing using `==` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not outputting anything since your `if` and `else` blocks are inside the `for` loop which iterates over `usernames`. Since `usernames` is an empty list, it's not iterating over anything, hence not reaching any of those conditional blocks.

You might want to put instead:

```
usernames = []
for username in usernames:
    if username is 'admin':
        print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
    else:
        print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")

if usernames:
    print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")
else:
    print("We need to find some users!")
```

That will print the last username in the `usernames` list twice, though.

Answer (score 0):

The first if-else should come inside the the for loop. The second if else block should come outside.

```
usernames = []

for username in usernames:

    if username is 'admin':
        print("Hey admin")
    else:
        print("Hello " + username + ", thanks!")

if usernames:
    print("Hello " + username + ", thanks again.")
else:
    print("Find some users!")
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response, it turns out that my second if-else statement being in my for loop was the problem, my output for this exercise is now displaying. :)